# Require javascript - can this be enforced through a server-side language

Tags: php, javascript, cross-browser

I have developed an ajax application framework using php/jQuery etc.  I would like to 'require' a user to have javascript enabled in order use the application (they are all internal apps so we are able to dictate the compatibility).

How can I detect if javascript is enabled on the serverside? please provide an example.

Comment: You can't, but you can read the response headers to guess the server type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't detect this server-side, you can however present a message client-side with the `<noscript>` tag, like this:

```
<noscript>
   <div class="alert">You need to enable JavaScript to use this site.</div>
</noscript>
```

`<noscript>` tags appear when the client doesn't have JavaScript enabled for whatever reason, so use them to present a message, element, etc to them...just give it some styling and you're good to go.

Comment: @Elzo Valugi : That's why he said _You can't detect this server-side_ which can be PHP (or ASP, JSP, etc...)

Comment: @Chouchenos then the noscript tag and explanation is irrelevant for the answer.

Comment: @Chouchenos: None of this lets the server know whether or not the client supports JavaScript.

Comment: @Ignacio - My contention is that's not necessary, if JS is disabled then hide your content and display a message that you need JavaScript support...what would PHP do differently if you *could* detect it?

Comment: I would like to do more than display an alert.  In fact I would like to have a kind of landing page... appending a message is insufficient for my liking.

Comment: @Nick: It could use simplified controls, e.g. discrete pulldowns for month, day, and year instead of a fancy calendar control.

Comment: @nick - How would you hide the content? to me this answer leaves that out.

Comment: @Derek - what would you do in PHP if you could?  Given this approach can hide all your normal content (e.g. `<style text="text/css">#content { display: none; }</style>`) and display another screen entirely (inside the `<noscript>` tag)...what else is your server-side script going to do?

Comment: @ignacio - I am not concerned with minor controls in the application or even graceful degredation here.  I would prefer to keep them contained in an entirely different section of the site if at all possible.

Comment: @Ignacio - This is solved by having gracefully degrading JavaScript...but that wasn't the question here, the question was to **require** JavaScript be enabled.

Comment: hmm... so something like... `<noscript>Message/page here</noscript><div style="display:none;>js_required_content_here</dv>` THEN unhide in JS when its loaded?  To me this seems more complicated then the js-cookie solution i'm looking for feedback on.

Comment: @Derek - No not that, say you have a `<div id="content">` with all your content, just stick a `<style text="text/css">#content { display: none; }</style>` inside the `<noscript>` tags so there's CSS to hide it if JavaScript's disabled, all the functionality changes are completely contained in the `<noscript>` tags.

Comment: @Elzo & Ignacio : Even if the OP asked for a validation of JS server (which seems _impossible_ and irrelevant), once you've statued that, why not giving him the most accurate and effective answer possible. The `<noscript>` is used for that case. You can use it in many ways depending of what you want the js to do or not. Anyway, it seems to have answer the OP's wishes ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. You will need to run it on the client, then have it either go to a specific URL, or contact the server via AJAX to notify it.

Answer (score 1):

Never done this but consider this webservice scenario, reductio ad absurdum:

1. assume that js is disabled and print an non-js content
2. register an ajax request just in case js will be active, that will pass a token to a server listener
3. if the listener receives a message in resonable timeframe return a new content and change the non-js content with it

This way you are covered for both scenarios. Another approach is the regular one with starts with the assumption that js is enabled. By the way,I guess about 90 % of webuser have js enabled, maybe even more.

Comment: yea i think its over 95% now... but it's really hard to get accurate facts on that kind of thing.  I like to minimize these types of risks when at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Upon some creative thinking... I think I am going to go with this solution - but I'd like feedback.**

### Set a cookie with JS on page load - detect if its there on the server-side

---

To me this seems viable because it's super light-weight and it fits my application structure nicely.  The idea of straying from my ajax call structure bothers me.

Comment: This requires an extra postback from the client though, do you really need do to that to present a "You need JavaScript" message?....what *else* is your PHP doing (or trying to do) when JavaScript is disabled?

Comment: But what if the client disables JavaScript *after* it has gotten the cookie? Or what is the client has cookies disabled?

Comment: @Nick - The system I'm using uses a wide variety of API calls.  I'd like to do this in order to help prevent any kind of unauthorized calls.  To me it made sense to require javascript to filter out any funny stuff right off the bat.

Comment: @Derek - Doing this does little to avoid unauthorized calls...this wouldn't stop a thing really.  I can make all those calls *without* a browser, much less JavaScript...security isn't really an issue here IMO, as in this doesn't solve any security issues.

Comment: @Nick - well the idea is that the api framework locks if a cookie isn't present.  No cookie set by JS - No API framework.  Wouldn't this rule out any kind of device/method of submiting data to my framework that wasn't a javascript compatibile browser?

Comment: (also, this is not sufficient to secure my api's nor is it the only security measure i'm taking)

Comment: @Derek - Nope, this wouldn't secure anything, as @Frxstrem suggested just enable JavaScript, get the cookie, turn it off...cookies are still sent.  There are a number of ways to bypass anything you do in JavaScript to disable anything :)

Comment: How about a dummy img tag inside the noscript element? It would require keeping an eye on simultaneous requests coming from the client, though.

Comment: It sounds like the best solution if you really want to detect it, but as Nick points out this does nothing at all from a security perspective.

Comment: Also, as an alternative to the <noscript> tag, you could look at using modernizr (http://www.modernizr.com/) which, in addition to its other awesome html5 feature detection, also detects javascript, so you can simply create rules like ".no-js div.foobar {display:none;}" to selectively hide or show different parts of your page without wrapping up bits in <noscript> tags.

Comment: @El Yobo - I tend to avoid plugins/extensions if at all possible... I don't like the idea of relying on individual's I don't know, ALthough i'll examine it.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it on the client side. If javascript is on it redirects to good site, else it display simple html page with error message.